# Find number of ways of selection of one or more letters from the word: AAAABBCCCDEF

Tags: permutations, combinations

Hello the question is above , I can't understand such type of questions, please help.

the answer is 479 but how does it come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $A$ occurs $4$ times, we can choose A in $4+1$ ways

So, the number of ways of selection of no or more letters from the word: **AAAABBCCCDEF** will be $N=(4+1)(2+1)(3+1)(1+1)(1+1)(1+1)$

Clearly, this contains one combination of choosing no letter

So, the number of ways of selection of one or more letters will be $N-1$

Comment: Thanks I got it, You always answer my questions lab bhattaharjee:)

Comment: @gaurav, my pleasure. Hope I can make the points clear

Comment: yo are very supporting, thanks again:)